# web parsing with python. Cannot get the whole page

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, python-requests

I'm trying to download web pages with python. Some pages are shown only partly. 
May be because they consist of several frames, but I'm not sure.

For example:

> https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/IBM/summary

Here is my code.

```
import requests
req = requests.get(URL) 
with open("d:\guru100.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(req.text)
```

Using `webdriver` is better. It returns more than previous code in yahoo site but still gives little in gurufocus site. The code is

```
from selenium import webdriver    
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/IBM/summary")
with open('d:\guru100.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

How can I get the whole page?

Comment: If you are using selenium then use `print(driver.page_source)` to get the whole html page after navigation.

Comment: I use driver.page_source. Still it gives only part of the page

Comment: Provide some time to page the load successfully and then get the `page_source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide some time to load the page successfully.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/IBM/summary")
time.sleep(10)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Thanks, it downloads more now. But still some graphs are hidden. Instead of graphs you can see "EMBED"